# Downloading Earth Engine images locally

Tags: javascript, python, geospatial, google-earth-engine, satellite-image

Is there a workaround to be able to download images acquired using Google Earth Engine (either the JS Earth Engine Code online or the Python API) that avoids using Google Drive or Google Cloud?

The files I'm trying to download are several GBs each and it will use up our Google Drive quota in no time, so does anyone know of a way where this can be bypassed to download locally or other means (e.g. to S3 bucket).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you explain why avoid Google Cloud Storage? GCS does not use Drive quota, and cost is about same as S3.

Comment: The charity I'm acquiring the images for already have AWS set up and are running everything through there. However, I will see if they're willing to look into GCS for the images.

I'm guessing there's no way to avoid Google services altogether and just download locally though?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [getDownloadURL](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-getdownloadurl) Image method.

For instance, in python:

```
image.getDownloadUrl({
        'scale': 10,
        'crs': 'EPSG:4326',
        'region': geojson
    })
```